# How to apply Magento Product Custom options on custom product page

Tags: custom-options, module, products-view

I have my custom page for product view in my module, the module calculates product price from a csv dynamically based on input. now i want some magento default product custom options to show and when customer change option's value, the product price also change like in default magento, but currently nothing happens when i changes options value.

Edit; this is the code i am using for updating price.

```
updateTotalPrice : function(price){

    this.TotalPrice = price;

    if($('step_1_price')){ //update price html of step 1
        $('step_1_price').update(this.CurrencySymbol+this.TotalPrice.toFixed(2));
    }

}
```

here "step_1_price" is

tag id containing price.
what i found is "reloadPrice" function in /catalog/product/view/options.phtml is responsible for it, but how to use it??? :(

Comment: put some sample code thus we can check

Comment: no..it is not enough

Comment: @AmitBera what should i post more. the only thing i want, is there any way i can catch the pricing value of these custom options and add to price when option values get change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i could solve it is that to use default tag for price and update my function for adding custom options like bellow:

```
updateTotalPrice : function(price){
    this.TotalPrice = price;
    optionsPrice.productPrice = this.TotalPrice;                         
    opConfig.reloadPrice();
}
```